# How to find whether django hits db

Tags: python, django

As per my knowledge, django querysets are lazy and wont hit db until evaluated, in such case after assigning the queryset to a key in a dict, will the following lines cause db to be hit everytime? Please advice

```
abc = model1.objects.all()

content = {
    'entry' : abc, # Once assigned will the below lines hits db?
    'entry_count' : abc.count(), # will this hit db
    'entry1_count' : abc.filter(name__icontains = 'a').count(), # will this hit db
    'entry2_count' : abc.filter(name__icontains = 'b').count(), # will this hit db again?
    }

return render(request, template, content}
```

Comment: No, simply assigning the queryset to a dictionary value will not magically evaluate it. `.count()` will hit the database but making a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query only.

Answer (score 1):

It will hit database in all that cases except first one.

Theoretical part can be seen in documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/

And you can use [django debug toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to see all SQL queries for each rendered page

Also you can see which query is being executed programmatically. For example for this line:

```
abc.count()
```

You can see SQL query by doing:

```
print(abc.count().explain())
```